# promise.all() doesn't return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

i wanna get user data.

user data value from 'getUserData(encodeURI(userId)).then((userData) => {...}' which is get from api using axios
is not problem

but function return await Promise.all(someList.map(...))
it was return [undefined, undefined, ...]

why await promise.all returned undefined array?

codes

```
app.use("/userinfo", (req, res) => res.json(getUsersData()));

async function getUserData(userId) {
  return await axios.get(`https://kr.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/${userId}?api_key=${riotApiKey}`)
};

async function getUsersData() {
  return await Promise.all(summonersId.map((userId, index) => {
    getUserData(encodeURI(userId)).then((userData) => {
      if (userData.status === 404) {
        throw new Error('no user')
      }
      console.log(userData.data)

      return {
        index: index,
        id: userData.id,
        name: userData.name
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('err', err.code)
    })
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the promise used in the `map` callback:

```
async function getUsersData() {
  return await Promise.all(summonersId.map((userId, index) => {
    // HERE: see "return" below
    return getUserData(encodeURI(userId)).then((userData) => {
      if (userData.status === 404) {
        throw new Error('no user')
      }
      console.log(userData.data)

      return {
        index: index,
        id: userData.id,
        name: userData.name
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('err', err.code)
    })
  }));
}
```

Comment: Other improvements: Rethrow the error in the `.catch()` so the errors there are not eaten/hidden.  And, in `return await Promise.all()`, the `await` is redundant and that can be changed to just `return Promise.all()`.  Both just return a promise.